# The binomial coefficient - prove this property

Tags: combinatorics, proof-verification

Prove that $$ {n\choose k}= \frac{n}{k} {n-1\choose k-1}$$
I have been thinking about it for a very long time and I have finally come to this solution: 
First of all, multiply by $k$:  
$${n\choose k}k = n {n-1 \choose k-1}$$ 
Let's say that we have a group of $n$ people. The left hand side first chooses $k$ of them who get a candy and then chooses $1$ from the chosen group to get a toy truck. 
The right hand side first chooses one person who gets a candy and a toy truck and then chooses $n-1$ people to get a candy.  

In both scenarios we have chosen exactly $k$ people, $k$ of them got a candy and $1$ of them got the toy truck. Thus, LHS and RHS are the same. 
Is this solution valid to any extent? 
What other ways to prove this are there? I tried induction - it works, too, but is a little tedious.

Comment: Yes, it is correct (*though the choice of candy and toy truck is a bit nonstandard, the more common would be selecting committee members and a leader for the committee*)

Comment: You're not allowed to use candy :P

Comment: @JMoravitz Another standard description is choosing a subset with one marked element. Either way, there are $\binom{n}{n-k,k-1,1}$ choices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way is this:\begin{align}\binom nk&=\frac{n(n-1)\ldots(n-k+1)}{k(k-1)\ldots 1}\\&=\frac nk\times\frac{(n-1)(n-2)\ldots(n-k+1)}{(k-1)(k-2)\ldots1}\\&=\frac nk\times\binom{n-1}{k-1}.\end{align}

Comment: I vote this as more valid. As standard practice, proving an equality requires one to start with either the LHS or RHS and, through manipulations and application of previously proven theorems, lemmas, etc, arrive at the other side. Typically manipulating terms from one side to the other is not allowed, though it can certainly provide some insight and a good starting point for a final proof.

Comment: I can see why someone would think it is more valid to use a direct proof as Jose has shown, but it is more revealing of the mathematician that shows he actually understands the counting concepts behind the combinatorical functions by in fact using counting to solve the problem, a much more difficult task that shows the OP really understands the underlying concepts of the math.

Comment: @Samuel I certainly don't feel that my proof is more valid than the one provided by the OP.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: Sorry if I made it sound like you did.  I was responding to sean's comment.

Comment: @Samuel Not at all. I didn't think that.

Comment: Your proof *is* more valid than OP's, since it works for any $n$ in a field of characteristic $0$, rather than just when $n$ is a positive integer. Of course, OP's proof can be lifted to that setting as well using the polynomial trick :)

Answer (score 2):

That is a lovely story proof and it sounds like you had fun coming up with it.

Well anyway, here is another which is perhaps a little more difficult to understand because it involves using the division principle. It is *really* no different mathematically, only in how you think about it:

**Left Hand Side**

You can pick $k$ people from $n$ for a $k$ person team  in $\binom{n}{k}$ ways.

**Right Hand Side**

You can pick the 'first person' of the $k$ person team in $\binom{n}{1}=n$ ways, then the rest of the team in $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$ ways. Each team in these $n\binom{n-1}{k-1}$ is counted $k$ times (once for every possible 'first person'). We must therefore divide $n\binom{n-1}{k-1}$ by this multiplicity $k$ in order to count each team only once. Giving $\frac{n}{k}\binom{n-1}{k-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct.  The methodology of proof you have chosen is a combinatorical proof, showing that 2 scenarios in fact count the same things.  See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_proof) for more info.